# How do I install Pyautogui?

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

I've downloaded the folder, I paste it but, when I run the test it says: No module: PIL.

Also, The pip install has the same error. When is almost concluded the installing process it says: Nomodule nademPIL.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the dependencies for it?

Comment: I don't see PIL as a dependency when I install it. They only thing it wanted was pypiwin32, which it installed automatically when I used pip. Note that I installed pywinauto 0.5.4 on Windows 7 with Python 2.7. If you actually need PIL, you can get it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in 0.9.34, so just try installing PyAutoGUI again.

Answer (score 0):

According the question **How do I install Pyautogui?**

Use blow command for python 3:

```
pip3 install pyautogui
```

If you get **No module: PIL.** error(in Python 3) then use this command.

```
pip3 install pillow
```

Use blow commend for python 2

```
pip install pyautogui
```

If you get **No module: PIL.** error(in Python 2) then use this command.

```
pip install pillow
```